# GCP API Gateway - Tracing not propagated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-api-gateway

Traicing is currently not supported for API Gateway based on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/tracing)

However, when the trace is "started" by some component in front of that e.g. LB those traces/headers are not visible in the log either.

API GW is ESP v2. I found following [startup options available](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options#tracing)
Is there a way how to pass those startup options to API gateway for example in terraform?

CORS and other configuration would be the same.

The only way I could think of was [OpenAPI extension](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions) where I don't see such option.

Propagating trace context to stackdriver logs I consider as bare minimum for the purpose of supportability.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Tracing is not supported in the current release of API Gateway. However you can submit trace data to Stackdriver Trace and view and analyze traces in the Google Cloud Console by using the Stackdriver Trace API to propagate trace context to Stackdriver logs in API Gateway. You can utilize the API by sending your API Gateway trace data in the request's header. By building a resource for the Stackdriver Trace API and customizing the header information that is provided along with the request, Terraform can be used to put this up.

Comment: @ChristianPaulAndaya I see that as logging support, it doesn't have anything with the ability to start or sample requests. I am not sure if I follow your suggestion. I am not aware of any way how to customize the API gateway. Can you put some reference to the solution you proposed? e.g. documentation, blog post, etc.

Comment: Sadly, it appears that API Gateway in GCP does not now provide trace context propagation to Stackdriver logs. You said that you attempted using startup options, but API Gateway does not support them. You may file a feature request in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/)